# Rails use model in the same namespace for belongs_to reference, how to reference model from outside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, module

I working on a Rails application, currently we structure the app by modules. Right now we have 2 separate model for users: `User` and `Freight::Customer::User`.

I have a new model `Freight::Customer::MembershipStatus` looks like this:

```
class Freight::Customer::MembershipStatus < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :customer, class_name: 'Freight::Customer'
  belongs_to :created_by, class_name: 'User'

  validates :from, presence: true
  validates :to, presence: true
  validates :customer, presence: true
  validates :status, presence: true
end
```

In this case, the `created_by` is reference to `User`. But when the code run `membership_status.created_by`, rails try to look for the `Freight::Customer::User`, I think it because Rails try to look for model within the same module first.

Is there a way to config this model to use the outer `User` model class?

Answer (score 6):

You can get user class using this type, try this.

```
class Freight::Customer::MembershipStatus < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :customer, class_name: 'Freight::Customer'
  belongs_to :created_by, class_name: '::User'

  validates :from, presence: true
  validates :to, presence: true
  validates :customer, presence: true
  validates :status, presence: true
end
```

Comment: Thank you, It works for me, been looking for this for awhile